# How do I add a custom region?

Tags: 8, theming, bootstrap-theme

How do I add a custom region in the bootstrap theme using Drupal 8?

I have installed a Bootstrap theme and now I want to add a custom region before the *Header* region.  What should I add in the theme .info file? How do I render it in the page template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your sub-theme's .info.yml file add the new region alongside the existing ones, e.g.

   ```
   regions:
     header: Header
     content: Content
     sidebar_first: 'Sidebar first'
     footer: Footer
     custom_region: 'Custom region'
   ```
2. Then in your page.html.twig file render it like so:

   ```
   {{ page.custom_region }}
   ```
3. Visit the Block layout admin page and assign some blocks to the region so it displays on the page.

Comment: Exactly, sir, it's working finally.